# In react lifecycle methods: doc.addEventListener('onmousemove', ... not working, but doc.onmousemove = ... is. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I'm missing something simple here I'm sure, but Im stumped.

Why do the addEventListener and removeEventListener functions NOT work inside these react lifecycle methods, but the commented out lines underneath them do?

```
  componentDidMount(){
    document.addEventListener('onmousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
    // document.onmousemove = this.handleMouseMove;
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    document.removeEventListener('onmousemove', this.handleMouseMove);
    // document.onmousemove = null;
  }

  handleMouseMove(){ ... }
```

I can just use the document.onmousemove = ... code and it works. But why don't the above lines work? I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event name is [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event), not the `onmousemove`.

The `onmousemove` is an event handler *property*.

So, correct code is:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', ...);
// OR
document.onmousemove = ...;
```